# BlueSky, remove missing row

Tags: dataset

I'd like to remove a missing row of data. My data set looks like this (assume they all line up, and are imported from excel)

Canada        1   5   3
Afghanistan   3   7   2
Brazil        2   4   6

How do I remove the line for Afghanistan?

I'm using BlueSky 10.0.0, R package version 8, on windows 10. I want to remove the row, using BlueSky menu.

Thanks

I read a guide to blueSky, couldn't find how to do this. I searched stackoverflow, couldn't find how to do this. I might not know the right terms to use to search.

Answer (score 0):

In the grid view of your data set, just choose the row with `left mouse click`

Then, with `right mouse click` you will get a menu to insert or delete a data row among others.